# SonataAdminBundle - override form block for a specific form field with form_theme

Tags: twig, symfony-forms, sonata-admin, sonata

Generally I would override form row using a form_theme with a block named like this:

```
{% block _name_row %}
{% endblock %}
```

But Sonata's fields use some dynamic block prefix which look like this:

```
name="s653d5ae3064d3[name]"
```

Thus, general approach can't be used, because I don't this prefix is dynamic. How can I override the field then?